# What happen if we have both hbm as well as annotation file while using Hibernate3?

Tags: java, hibernate

My question is not so good,But I am curious to know this.

Suppose I have 10 tables, and I am using Hibernate3, anything wrong would happens, when I will use Annotation for 5 tables, and HBM files for 5 tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well normally Hibernate will first process your annotation config, and then he'll process the hbm files. If it comes across a situation in which a configuration parameter is declared via annotation and then re-declared (with maybe a different value) via hbm files, the value from the hbm file will replace the one declared via annotation. Otherwise, non-overlapping config params from annotations and hbm file will be "merged" together.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/ch01.html#setup-configuration

Answer (score 2):

You can perfectly mix them. In fact XML takes precedence over annotations, so you can override settings in annotations with XML. Sometimes useful.